# Image sizing in application

Tags: iphone

I have about **90 images** in my app what size i should pick for pixels **320x240 or 640x480**. In **UIViewController** i have **UIImageView and UITextView**. Should i go with **320x240** and the format of the image can be **JPEG** or it should be **PNG** only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it depends on your requirement.
[Apple Human Interface Guideline](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html) will help you a lot to take a proper decision.